# Where can I find a replacement cable for PowerA's Spectra Enhanced Wired Controller?

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

I have a Power A Spectra Enhanced Wired Controller for XBOX One:

[image: Screenshot of the controller.]

My snap-lock detachable cable broke and I'm having trouble finding a replacement. I've searched Amazon and Google but so far I've turned up nothing.

Does anyone have an idea on where I can find a replacement cable, or should I just buy a new controller?

Comment: Welcome, again, to the Arqade! You could improve this question by including images of your broken component, along with a link to where you initially purchased the controller (if applicable) and which console the controller is for. I'll do my best to assist you with that momentarily. Finally, if you have some time, please take a moment to complete the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: It turns out, [others have had this problem](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/xbox/forum/all/replacement-part/01bcb4f1-70e5-4f65-815f-49dbc72bdbc0) and the recommended course of action is to reach out to [PowerA support](https://www.powera.com/support/).

Comment: its for xbox one